# How to show/hide custom product tab on product detail page according to product's custom attribute value?

Tags: product, custom, hide

I have custom attribute named "show_tab" in products. I have enable/disable value for this product. I want to show custom product tab according to attribute's value. Custom product tab is created successfully according to below way. But i don't know how to apply product specific condition in xml file?

> To start with create a file ‘catalog_product_view.xml’ in the
> app/code///view/frontend/layout folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
           <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" template="VendorName_ModuleName::custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
               <arguments>
                   <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
               </arguments>
           </block>
       </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

> Now created the custom_tab.phtml file in
> app/code///view/frontend/layout folder and added
> the below

```
<?php echo "This is Custom tab in product detail page"; ?>
```

How to apply condition in above code? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create custom block for it like below. And apply your condition like below.

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Product;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Tab extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_registry;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _toHtml() 
    {
        if($this->getProduct()) {
            $showTab = $this->getProduct()->getShowTab();
            if (!$showTab) {
                return '';
            }
        }
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }
}
```

> Now call above custom block file in xml file indtead of block
> "Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
           <block class="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Product\Tab" name="custom.tab" template="VendorName_ModuleName::custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
               <arguments>
                   <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
               </arguments>
           </block>
       </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try the below solution:**

**create events.xml in your module**

**[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
       <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="load_custom_tab_handler" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**In your [Vendor][Module]\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore.php file write below code**

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
       ............
       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
       ............
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

        if (!$product) {
          return $this;
        }
        if (!$product->getshowTab()) { // your condition
           $layout = $observer->getLayout();
           $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('catalog_product_view_customtab');
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Cretae catalog_product_view_customtab.xml**

**[Vendor][Module]\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view_customtab.xml** file write below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   
    <body> 
        <referenceBlock name="custom.tab" remove="true" />
    </body>
    
</page>
```